# Struts and Hibernate : Updation of record

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I have created a registration form using struts and storing that value in database using hibernate. After submitting the form user can see all the details. I want that user can edit their details

My code is

```
public Contact edit(Long id) { //id of selected record
        System.out.println("Updation Selected Record");
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Contact contact = (Contact) session.load(Contact.class, id);

        if(null != contact) {
              session.update(contact);
        }   
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return contact;
    }
```

But it is not working .How to display the value of selected record in textbox so tht user can edit it and again save it.

Answer (score 1):

Your  method makes no sense: it loads a contact from the database, doesn't make any change to the contact, and updates the contact.

The edit method should either

- load the contact from database, and modify the fields of the contacts (using values coming from the struts form)
- or take a modified, detached contact as argument (stored in the session when user asked to modify the contact, for example), and then update or merge this contact

Comment: ya, i agree . I knw it just load the selected record from database.thts my question how to display it in struts form so that user can modify the content.